# iPhone Memory release issue

Tags: iphone

I've some doubts regarding dealloc function in iPhone program. Is it required to give [self.object_name release] or [object_name release] is ok?..
I've this strange problem in my dealloc function is like this.

```
-(void) dealloc {
   [self.listOfDates release];
   [self.listOfDescriptions release];
   [super dealloc];
 }
```

But program crashes giving EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. Here both objects are NSMutableArray instances allocated with alloc in init function for the class. The same function without self works fine i.e

```
-(void) dealloc {
    [listOfDates release];
    [listOfDescription release];
    [super dealloc];
 }
```

Here is how I declared the property

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *listOfDates;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *listOfDescription;
```

In the implementation file I sysnthesized this and inside the init function I've allocated these variables like this

```
self.listOfDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.listOfDescription = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

So is it required to give self ? What am I missing here?

Issue resolved when I removed mutableCopy function which I had used to copy instance of NSMutableArrays which were passed as argument to the init function as shown below

```
-(id)initWithDate:(NSMutableArray *)dates andDescription:(NSMutableArray*)descriptions
{
    if(self = [super initWithNibName:@"DateDescriptionControl" bundle:nil])
    {
        self.listOfDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.listOfDescription = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        self.listOfDates = [dates mutableCopy];
        self.listOfDescription = [description mutableCopy]; 

    }

   return self;
}
```

After removing the mutableCopy the dealloc is now not throwing EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. So where have I made the mistake I still can't figure out :(

Comment: Are listOfDates and listOfDescription properties of the class?

Comment: Yes it is the property of the class with nonatomic and retain

Comment: You should not use `self.` at all here.

Comment: I think with or without self both should be ok. But I don't know why you get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS with using self. Would you please reveal more code regarding allocation/initialization/deallocation?

Comment: I've updated with code for initialization

Comment: I assume that you get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS because you over-release something. However in your code I see over-retain(memory leak) not over-release. So I guess the real problem happens in somewhere else.

Comment: in initWithDate, the empty array [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] you created does nothing because later you get a mutableCopy of something. Why?

Comment: in initWithDate, self.listOfDates = [dates mutableCopy]; will cause memory leak. You need to release what mutableCopy returns. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087689/who-is-responsible-for-releasing-objects-in-an-array-when-copying/1088943#1088943 for more explanation. I suggest that don't use dot-notation in init and dealloc.

Comment: By the way, you're useing mutable objects as properties. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816720/whats-the-best-way-to-use-obj-c-2-0-properties-with-mutable-objects-such-as-nsm/816942#816942 may help.

Comment: Yeah i found mutableCopy was causing a leak. I've removed it. before removing mutableCopy as i mentioned in the dealloc if i don't use self. notation no bad access comes

Comment: You removed mutableCopy? Don't you need it in initWithDate?

Comment: Now i'm just assigning them
self.listOfDates = dates;
self.listOfDescription = description;

Answer (score 2):

self is not required for releasing in dealloc function.

Answer (score 2):

In dealloc you have two choices:

```
[foobar release];
```

or

```
self.foobar = nil;
```

The second one is equivalent to writing `[self setFoobar:nil]` and it is inside the setFoobar: method is where the previous value is being released (assuming the property was defined as using retain or copy). I tend to prefer the first form, where you just send `release` directly to the object, but either will do.

Writing `[self.foobar release]` should technically be OK, although if you later call `self.foobar = nil` the object will be released a second time (and cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

Answer (score 0):

`self.something` means `[self something]` since the dot means property syntax. What you want is `self->something`.

Comment: `self->something` is valid but unnecessary and strange.

Comment: It's the minimal change if the asker want to keep the `self`. Of course the 2nd code in the question is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

yes,

[object release];

should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem you are having is caused by this code:

```
self.listOfDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

When a property is "retain" and you access it via the setter then the object assigned to it should be in the autorelease pool, like so:

```
self.listOfDates = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

But, this is kind of ugly and the NSMutableArray provides a nice constructor that does this for you automatically:

```
self.listOfDates = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Your code is not using ARC, so the object should be in the autorelease pool. If you were using ARC then the rules are a little different.

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice(Non ARC).
Within your Interface Declare Varibal like below

```
NSMutableArray *_listOfDates;
NSMutableArray *_listOfDescription;
```

And your Setters should be below. (as same as your code)

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *listOfDates;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *listOfDescription;
```

In your implementation

```
@synthesize listOfDates = _listOfDates, listOfDescription = _listOfDescription;
```

In initialization

```
-(id)initWithDate:(NSMutableArray *)dates andDescription:(NSMutableArray*)descriptions
{
    if(self = [super initWithNibName:@"DateDescriptionControl" bundle:nil])
    {
        NSMutableArray *tempListOfDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.listOfDates = tempListOfDates;
        [tempListOfDates release];

        NSMutableArray *tempListOfDescription = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.listOfDescription = tempListOfDescription;
        [tempListOfDescription release];
    }
}
```

in dealloac

```
-(void) dealloc {
    [_listOfDates release];
    [_listOfDescription release];
    [super dealloc];
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use [object release] to release the instance variable. Using "self" is not necessary.

Comment: Im not sure why his answer was down-voted.  You are NOT supposed to use accessor (self.) in dealloc.  Straight form Apple. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html.     Perhaps you down voted him because he said "not necessary" instead of "not recommend", but from the looks of it, benzado is incorrect and futureelite is spot on.